# Bash transpose not working correctly

Tags: bash

I am writing a script that needs to work on Ubuntu and Mint in bash. I read a string like this, `4:3:cdefg`, from a named fifo pipe, two numbers and a word with a colon inbetween. Then, in a bash script, I try to replace every *':' colon* character with a *'\n' newline* character. Instead of the output like the following:

```
4
3
cdefg
```

I get

```
4 3 cdefg
```

where all the colons have been replaced with a ' ' space character.

The command in the script is

```
echo $line | tr ':' '\n'
```

where $line is read in from a named pipe in a loop. It works perfectly if I try it directly in the terminal

```
echo "4:3:cdefg" | tr ':' '\n'
```

What could be wrong? If I understand correctly, the named pipe only passes received bytes over to the listening processes and does not change the coding, so it should work in the script as well.
I run the script in bash, not sh, as I have `#!/bin/bash` in the first line. I've also tried running the script like `bash -xv <script name>` with the same results.

All advice greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't actually post the code you run, but here's what I imagine you're doing:

```
$ cat yourscript
line="4:3:cdefg"
transposed=$(echo $line | tr ':' '\n')
echo $transposed

$ bash yourscript
4 3 cdefg
```

Here's what [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net) has to say about it:

```
$ shellcheck yourscript
In yourscript line 3:
echo $transposed
     ^-- SC2086: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.
```

And here's what happens if we apply its suggestion:

```
$ cat yourscript
line="4:3:cdefg"
transposed=$(echo $line | tr ':' '\n')
echo "$transposed"

$ bash yourscript
4
3
cdefg
```